# form submit by clicking on anchor tag in IE11

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to update some old code that works correctly on all versions of IE except IE11. When an anchor tag is clicked a javascript function is run. The function . All that the function does is that it gets certain values from the DOM and then submits a form using the post action.
I understand that IE11 submit does not work if the input element does not have a name. Here, the submit is done by clicking on an anchor tag- I tried adding a name and id to the anchor tag but it is still not working.
Any idea on how to get it to work. Following is the anchor tag.

```
<a class="nohigh"  href="javascript:getClassDetails('<%=Id%>');">
```

Following is the javascript function:

```
function getClassDetails(a){
 var classId = document.getElementById(classIdRow ).value;
 var courseId = document.getElementById(courseIdRow).value;
 document.getElementById('val1').value = classId 
 document.getElementById('val2').value = courseId 
 document.getElementById('clasCourseForm').submit();
}
```

Comment: The syntax of your function statement is just .... weird.

Comment: Weird as in nowhere near valid JS.

Comment: classIdRow and courseIdRow are defined where?

Comment: Perhaps you could also include the code for the html form as well?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console (press f12 and look at the console tab when you run refresh the page and click the link) as I made a quick form doing a similar thing and it works in ie11: http://jsfiddle.net/6dc7twn3/1/.  unless you have defined them as globals, I would say `classIdRow` and `courseIdRow` are not set so the `.value` may throw an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it - by adding both a name and id to the form.

Comment: For future readers, it would be helpful to edit your original code sample and add it to your answer with the properties you added to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The function that you want should be:

```
function getClassDetails(a){
 var classId = document.getElementById(classIdRow).value; // assuming classIdRow is defined
 var courseId = document.getElementById(courseIdRow).value; // assuming courseIdRow is defined
 document.getElementById('val1').value = classId;
 document.getElementById('val2').value = courseId;
 document.getElementById('clasCourseForm').submit();
}
```

That's at least assuming that all the JavaScript you have up there ^ is verbatim.

Comment: Sorry- I messed up while copying the code. fixed it.

Comment: you sure?  or did you just replace your code with my answer's content :)

Comment: @Mary So, did this fix the problem, or do you mean you fixed copying of the code to the question?

Comment: @sircapsalot : Well, this is working code and was looking into why it wasn't working on IE11. Also, I know I have enough integrity to not have to lie about it.

Comment: However, not enough clarity to not be ambiguous. Twice.

Comment: The error that comes up is  "Unable to get property 'submit' of undefined or null reference". It looks like it is unable to find the form. The form has been defined with a name clasCourseForm. My question is since the form submit is being done by a javascript function by explicitly calling the form.submit, is there anything  special that needs to be done for IE11.

Comment: I was able to fix this by adding both a name and id for the form

Answer (score 1):

[edit: removed the original answer, as the question has been changed to correct the syntax]

In addition, the JS code has other weirdness, in that the function is accepting a parameter (`a`) but never uses it within the function. There's almost certainly some kind of logic mistake involved there which you'll want to look into.